# Объединить результат 2-х join

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы
firm
`id | title`
`1  | "t"`
`2  | "t2"`

firm_property
`id | firm_id | property_id`
`1  | 1       | 100`
`2  | 1       | 200`
`3  | 2       | 200`

Мне надо получить список фирм, которые имеют property_id  и 100 и 200.
Делал помощью `LEFT JOIN` вот так:

```
SELECT * FROM firm f
LEFT JOIN firm_property fp ON fp.firm_id = f.id AND fp.property_id = 100
LEFT JOIN firm_property fp1 ON fp1.firm_id = f.id AND fp1.property_id = 200
```

В итоге у меня выбирались все данные. Если заменить `LEFT JOIN` на `INNER JOIN` то вообще ничего не выбирается.
Хотелось бы как-нибудь объединить результаты 2-х `INNER JOIN`-ов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` работали как раз так, как я хотел, но видимо я не те значения в запрос вставил и получил неверный результат.

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно поняла, нужны фирмы со значениями и 100 и 200 (т.е. только 100 или только 200 не подходит). Если так, то это можно сделать следующим запросом:

```
SELECT firm_property.firm_id, firm.title
FROM  firm_property INNER JOIN
   firm ON firm_property.firm_id = firm.id
WHERE  (firm_property.property_id IN (100, 200))
GROUP BY firm_property.firm_id, firm.title
HAVING  (COUNT(*) = 2)
```